# Using WordPress function inside webservice outside wordpress root

Tags: php, wordpress, web-services

I have some issues with calling vanilla Wordpress functions inside my web service directory on my server.

I have a structure like this:

```
Root

- webservice
- - service.php
- wordpress
- - wordpress-root
```

I started with google this problem and find some solutions like this...

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress-root/wp-load.php');
```

and

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress-root/wp-blog-header.php');
```

I adding these lines into my service.php.
Now my browser starts to redirect me to the following URL and throw an error
 `wp-admin/install.php`

```
 The requested URL /wp-admin/install.php was not found on this server.
```

Do someone have a solid solution to this problem?

**//Edit**

After debugging figured out that the redirect is throw after this line of code in the function.php

```
    /*
 * Loop over the WP tables. If none exist, then scratch install is allowed.
 * If one or more exist, suggest table repair since we got here because the
 * options table could not be accessed.
 */
$wp_tables = $wpdb->tables();
foreach ( $wp_tables as $table ) {
    // The existence of custom user tables shouldn't suggest an insane state or prevent a clean install.
    if ( defined( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE' ) && CUSTOM_USER_TABLE == $table )
        continue;
    if ( defined( 'CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE' ) && CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE == $table )
        continue;
    // Error throw after this lines
    if ( ! $wpdb->get_results( "DESCRIBE $table;" ) )
        continue;
```

Comment: So if you navigate to `/wordpress-root/` what happens?

Comment: @WheatBeak `require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress-root/');`throws an error "Warning: require"...

Comment: Your WordPress installation has to be valid before you can load it from another directory.

Answer (score 0):

redirection to install.php happens when wordpress thinks this is a new installation. And this happens when wordpress can't find a specific entry in the database. (options table with option_name == 'siteurl')

Open the file functions.php and search for the function [is_blog_installed](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_blog_installed). Then debug why this function thinks wordpress is not installed.

My guess is that the config file could not be read or some variables are empty. Check also for correct file permissions.

You could also try to set the variable by your script. See also [site_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url) function.

Comment: Thank you. That was a good hint. The redirect seems to get after this line of code.
`if ( ! $wpdb->get_results( "DESCRIBE $table;" ) )
   continue;`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-blog-header.php')
```

or

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php')
```

source
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/47049/10911

Comment: Thank you for your help, but that didn´t solve my problem.